# C++ Can't edit a string in function

Tags: c++, string, function

I'm stumped. Really can't figure this one out.

```
int main(){
    string blah = "text";
    example(&blah);
}

void example(string *h){
    *h[3]='l';
}
```

What I'm trying to do in the above function is edit the 4th character of the original string without using a global variable. I'd have thought this would have worked as I know I can do something similar with ints. Guessing it's something to do with string/char conversion but I'm unable to find much information on the web.

Comment: operator precedence: `(*h)[3]`. But if you want to just make it simple, pass by reference: `void example(string& h) { h[3] = '1'; }`.

Comment: `std::string*` eeewwww...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do: `(*h)[3]='l';`.

that's happens because of the operator precedence, `[]` is prior to `*`.

Comment: Sweet and simple. Legend.

Answer (score 7):

That's not C, it is C++, pass by reference to make your life easier:

```
void example(string & h){
    h[3]='l';
}
```

It makes about zero sense to pass it as a pointer in C++ (in that particular use case), that's "C style" pass by reference, made obsolete by the introduction of references in C++.

Typically, you'd want to pass as a pointer if you intend to use pointer arithmetic, something which has mostly been rendered obsolete by the C++ standard library containers, or for the sake of conforming to some established library API - there are plenty which heavily use pointers, but for a slightly different intent than your use case.

BTW, `std::string` has an `at()` method, which might be a little more elegant to use with a pointer:

```
h->at(3) = 'l';
```

Of course, you could call the `[]` operator as a function from the pointers as well:

```
h->operator [](3) = 'l';
```

but it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: There is one argument for passing by pointer rather than reference: clarity of interface. It is not visible at the call site if an object is passed as const reference or non-const reference. The extra `&` needed to pass an object through a pointer makes the potential change visible at the call site (e.g. google style guide enforces this)

Comment: @stefan - true that, but in most contemporary IDEs all you need to do is hover over the call to see the function signature. And you usually get it when you type the opening parenthesis for the call as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simple: `*h[3]` is equivalent to `*(h[3])`, not `(*h)[3]` because of operator precedence.

There are three ways to circumvent this:

1. changing the interface:

In C++ you're allowed to pass objects *by reference*:

```
void example(std::string& h)
//                      ^
{
    h[3] = '1';
}
```

All changes made to `h` inside the function `example` are visible "outside of the function".

2. leaving the interface as-is:

if changing the interface is not an option, you may still make your life easier

```
void example(std::string* h_ptr)
{
    assert( h_ptr != nullptr ); // make sure you didn't pass a NULL pointer
    std::string& h = *h_ptr;    // create a reference from a non-NULL pointer
    h[3] = '1';
}
```

3. be absolutely precise and live in a dangerous world:

You have to be very careful about operator precedence. Better avoid this solution.

```
void example(std::string* h)
{
   (*h)[3] = '1'; // be explicit on the order you want (you will often make mistakes!)
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with just `assert(h_ptr)`?  Readability?

Comment: @ddriver There's nothing wrong, but it's personal preference. I consider `assert(h_ptr != nullptr)` to be very much more readable.

Comment: "very much more" - that sounds plenty ;) On a side note, I find it less than optimal, not only is it longer to type, but it adds another level of reasoning, somehow it sounds cleaner to ask "if this is true" than "if this is not untrue" :)

Comment: @ddriver I like the statement "this pointer is not the nullptr" way more than "this pointer is true". A pointer isn't "true", it's either valid or invalid.

Comment: The very fact you are using `if` makes it resolve to a boolean, which is either true or false, besides a pointer can pass such a check and still be invalid if it points to the wrong address. I agree that sometimes implicit conversions are bad, and they are way too common in C++ and in many cases make the code less readable, but not in that particular scenario, at least that's how it works for me. Still "is it true that water is wet" sounds a bit better than "is it not true that water is not wet".

Comment: To put it in your own words `if (ptr)` would be "is the pointer valid" while `if (ptr != nullptr)` would be "is the pointer not invalid" because `nullptr` will decay to "invalid" - the first is still somewhat cleaner IMO, albeit a bit cryptic if you know absolutely nothing about programming whatsoever.

Comment: @ddriver I don't read `if(ptr) ` as "is ptr valid", but as "is ptr true" which is very weird. As I've said (and I don't think we need to debate it): it's personal preference. I also consider `if (!ptr)` very weird. I don't think there is harm in being explicit (everyone can understand `ptr != nullptr`, not everyone knowns `ptr` will convert to boolean).

Comment: Now you are contradicting yourself, just the previous comment you said "a pointer isn't true" now you read it as "is ptr true", and you said it can only be valid or invalid, but you don't read it as valid - very weird indeed ;). BTW, to each his own, I am not trying to convince or force you, just trying to figure out your logic. Alas, I will have to live without it.

Comment: @ddriver I'm not contradicting myself, you just don't seem to understand that there is a difference between "valid" and "true".

Comment: OK, OK, at least now I know I don't understand ;)